# Generate a Monotonic Function

Tags: code-golf, random, generation

## Overview

In this challenge, your task is to randomly generate a [monotonic mathematical function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) between two sets.

## Input

Your inputs are two positive integers `s` and `n`.

After getting these inputs, your program shall generate a [random](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1325/32014) mathematical function `f` from the set `{0,1,...,s-1}n` to `{0,1,...,s-1}`.
In other words, `f` is a "rule" that takes in an `n`-tuple of integers between `0` and `s-1`, and returns one such integer.
Additionally, `f` should be *monotonic* in the following sense.
If `A` and `B` are two `n`-tuples such that `A[i] ≥ B[i]` holds for every coordinate `i`, then `f(A) ≥ f(B)`.

The exact distribution of the monotonic functions `f` doesn't matter, as long as each such function has a positive probability of being generated (assuming a perfect RNG).

## Output

Your output shall be an enumeration of the inputs and outputs of `f`.
It shall contain all `n`-tuples of integers between `0` and `s-1` in some order, each one being followed by the corresponding output of `f`.
The exact output format is flexible (within reason).

## Examples

The inputs `s = 3` and `n = 2` might produce the output

```
(0, 0) 0
(0, 1) 1
(0, 2) 2
(1, 0) 0
(1, 1) 1
(1, 2) 2
(2, 0) 1
(2, 1) 1
(2, 2) 2
```

It contains all the pairs over the set `{0, 1, 2}` exactly once, and each one is followed by its `f`-value.
The monotonicity condition is also satisfied.
The tuples are given here in lexicographical order, but this is not necessary.

As another example, `s = 2` and `n = 4` might produce

```
(0, 0, 0, 0) 0
(0, 0, 0, 1) 0
(0, 0, 1, 0) 0
(0, 0, 1, 1) 0
(0, 1, 0, 0) 1
(0, 1, 0, 1) 1
(0, 1, 1, 0) 1
(0, 1, 1, 1) 1
(1, 0, 0, 0) 0
(1, 0, 0, 1) 1
(1, 0, 1, 0) 0
(1, 0, 1, 1) 1
(1, 1, 0, 0) 1
(1, 1, 0, 1) 1
(1, 1, 1, 0) 1
(1, 1, 1, 1) 1
```

The following are all possible outputs for `s = 2` and `n = 2` (up to reordering the tuples); your program should randomly output one of them:

```
(0,0) 0
(0,1) 0
(1,0) 0
(1,1) 0
-------
(0,0) 0
(0,1) 0
(1,0) 0
(1,1) 1
-------
(0,0) 0
(0,1) 0
(1,0) 1
(1,1) 1
-------
(0,0) 0
(0,1) 1
(1,0) 0
(1,1) 1
-------
(0,0) 0
(0,1) 1
(1,0) 1
(1,1) 1
-------
(0,0) 1
(0,1) 1
(1,0) 1
(1,1) 1
```

## Rules and Scoring

You can write a full program or a function.
The lowest byte count wins, and [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.
Code with explanation is preferred.

There are no restrictions on time complexity, but I'll give a **bonus of -15 %** if your solution is always guaranteed to finish in a certain amount of time (depending on the inputs, and assuming a perfect RNG that runs in constant time).

Comment: It might help if you completely enumerate all of the possible functions for a tiny case such as s=2 n=2. I had to read the description a few times to grasp how the randomness would come into play.

Comment: @Sparr Good idea; edited.

Comment: is bounded runtime a requirement? I'm contemplating a solution that produces random functions until it finds a monotonic one.

Comment: @Sparr I think I'll add a bonus for bounded runtime, so such a solution won't be disqualified.

Comment: @Zgarb - perhaps you should make a large bonus for solutions that are both bounded and likely to finish within an hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, 35 bytes (38 - 15% = 31.45 farther down)

```
#I!sm><FhMds<MCeMd^JC,mOQK^UQvzK2JB
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23I%21sm%3E%3CFhMds%3CMCeMd%5EJC%2CmOQK%5EUQvzK2JB&input=2%0A3&debug=0)

Input is in the format:

```
n
s
```

Output is in the format:

```
[[value, tuple], [value, tuple], ...]
```

Simply generates random possibilities and tests them.

---

Alternative 37 byte version which I believe qualifies for the bonus:

```
Of!sm><FhMds<MCeMd^T2mC,d^UQvz^UQ^Qvz
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Of%21sm%3E%3CFhMds%3CMCeMd%5ET2mC%2Cd%5EUQvz%5EUQ%5EQvz&input=2%0A2&debug=0)

This starts by generating all possible monotonic functions, then outputs one at random. It is much slower, and tops out at `2,2`.

Comment: Nice example with input `3, 2`. Unfortunately, I didn't even get a response for `3, 3` in the online pyth executor. Is there an endless loop for this combination?!

Comment: @bobbel The online executor has a timeout, I think. I try it locally.

Comment: @bobbel It's not so much an infitie loop has a very slow one. It also works for `2, 4`, but not much else.

Comment: @bobbel I added something even slower.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 40 bytes - 15% = 34 bytes

```
q~1$\m*\1$,m*{W$\.+2m*{:.<2b}%1&!},mR]zp
```

This approach generates all valid functions and then selects on at random. Run time is at least **O(s<sup>2s<sup>n</sup></sup>)**, but constant for a given input.

I doubt this is what the OP had in mind, but it is *guaranteed to finish in a certain amount of time (depending on the inputs[...])* and therefore qualifies for the bonus.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~1%24%5Cm*%5C1%24%2Cm*%7BW%24%5C.%2B2m*%7B%3A.%3C2b%7D%251%26!%7D%2CmR%5Dzp&input=2%202).

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 64 bytes (-15% = 54.4)

```julia
g(s,n)=(K=rand(0:s-1,ntuple(n,i->s));for i=1:n K=sort(K,i)end;K)
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
function g(s,n)
  # Generates a random n-dimensional array with s per dimension
  # and all values being integers between 0 and s-1
  K=rand(0:s-1,ntuple(n,i->s))
  # Loop over the various dimensions
  for i=1:n
    # Sort in the current dimension
    K=sort(K,i)
  end
  return K
end
```

This will run quickly, with the only possible issue being with memory for large enough s and n (g(10,10) has to produce a 10^10 array, so obviously it's going to run out of memory - even if each number is one byte, that's 10 gigabytes of data).

Output is 1-based indexing, so to determine the result for a given input, you need to add one to each input value. For example, to find f(1,2,6,0,3), you need to examine `K[2,3,7,1,4]`.